# Why is X using only two of my monitors?

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, x-windows

I have a desktop machine with Intel QM77MK motherboard and NVidia Quadro 600 PCIe card. The motherboard has DisplayPort, DVI-I and DVI-D connections, while the Quadro has DVI and DisplayPort.

I've got DVI-connected monitors on:

- Motherboard DVI-D
- Quadro DisplayPort
- Quadro DVI

When I boot CentOS 6.5, one monitor shows the BIOS and boot process, but then remains in text mode - if I Ctrl-Alt-F2 to another display, that screen is the one that text happens on. But... My Gnome 2 desktop is displayed on the other two screens. Display Preferences can only see those two monitors.

The onboard graphics are clearly working, as I can interact in text mode, but how can I get X to recognise the extra monitor and extend the desktop to it?

Comment: Can you give us the output of `xrandr`?

Comment: Here's the output: http://pastebin.com/c5LVQNWD - although it seems to show only two screens attached, the third screen is still displaying the completed "CentOS 6.5" bar that appears on loading the OS!

Comment: I think showing what your xorg.conf file is probably what'd be most useful at this point.  Multiheaded systems are nothing new, but the issue here appears to be that your X is only looking at the nvidia card, while the onboard card is left hanging behind as a console display only. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/multihead#Example:_dualhead_configuration_using_relative_coordinates will probably be useful to you (but please, let's get a formal answer to this question rather than yet another abandoned question thanks to a link answer).

Comment: Please post the output of `lspci`.

Comment: `lspci` output: http://pastebin.com/qTQdasLc

Comment: `xorg.conf`: http://pastebin.com/0sviDbQN

Comment: Sorry for the delay - been away over the weekend.

Comment: @0xDAFACADE and @harrymc; do you have time to have a look at the files, please? I'm not sure how to load something that will use the onboard card, unfortunately.